# Cause Of SQL Connection Error

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, visual-studio

Within my ASP.NET C# WebForms app I am attempting to connect to my SQL Database.

Upon connection I get the error:

> ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

I've attempted to google what this error means but the results do not clearly explain whats wrong. *Can you tell me what exactly is wrong (its not finding the database file, it found the file but the database file is incorrect version, etc.)?*

These are the steps I have performed:

- Create a local database using VS2013. The file is located in 'MyProjectPath\App_Data\Pages.mdf'
- The database is populated with a table and rows
- I have connected to the server by 'Server Explorer->Connect To Server->Type in my computer username'. No errors appear
- In the Server Explorer I have tested my connection to the database and it succeeded.
- Connection is 'Microsoft SQL Server Database File (SqlClient)'
- I have copied the 'ConnectionString' to web.config. One important thing is that the string contains quotation marks and I have to remove these.
- Do I need to start an external application like SQL Server Management Studio or something?

Connection String:

> Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename="C:\VERY_LONG_PATH_THAT_HAS_SPACES\App_Data\Pages.mdf";Integrated Security=True

I remove the quotations:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MySQLConnStr" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\VERY_LONG_PATH_THAT_HAS_SPACES\App_Data\Pages.mdf;Integrated Security=True"/>
</connectionStrings>  

// My simple connection code where the runtime error occurs
try
{
    using (OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySQLConnStr"].ConnectionString))
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Response.Write(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Is it necessary for you to use OdbcConnection? Prefer OLEDB.

Answer (score 0):

Hi to make ODBC connection you need to have driver installed. You can make sql connection and this should work..
// Change your simple connection code to

```
try
{
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySQLConnStr"].ConnectionString);
    connection.open();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Response.Write(ex.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try one by one below three solutions, it will help you to solve your problem.

1. You need to configure DSN in Administration Tools => ODBC, When install driver choose for all users instead current user
2. Try to look on your server for the ODBC Data Source Administrator that can be found in Control Panel --> Administrative Tools --> Data Sources (ODBC). (On 64 bit Windows systems, you'll have to explicitly call c:\windows\syswow64\odbcad32.exe ) and add the driver to the System DSN tab.
3. If the ODBC driver was not 64 bit, Try to compile your application as an x86 process and it will work.